# How to shift hrule to the right (or insert horizontal space before hrule) using plain-TeX commands?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, rules, plain-tex

I can't seem to shift an `\hrule` to the right so that it starts some distance after the left margin.

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \hrule width5pt
  hello
\end{document}
```

output

[image]

wanted output (red segment represents horizontal space preceding hrule)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows; note that `varwidth` does several things that make this unusable in that context.

```
\moveright0.2cm\vbox{\hrule width5pt}\nointerlineskip
\noindent hello

\bye
```

In order to trick `varwidth`, you can do

```latex
\documentclass[margin=1mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\vbox{\moveright0.2cm\vbox{\hrule width5pt}}\nointerlineskip
  hello

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you have to use `\vrule` instead, and you'll need more boxes and an explicit `dimen`, at least as far as I can see.

Here, I'm assuming that you want your rule horizontally shifted by the width of the letter "h"; hence, I'm explicitly defining a `\newbox` called `\hhbox`, which is an `\hbox` containing only the letter "h".  I'm then defining a `dimen`, `\hwid`, which is the width of `\hhbox`.

We then put together a `\vbox` which contains two `\hbox`es, one with the rule shifted to the right by the width of `\hwid`, and one with the word "hello".  I've used explicit heights for the `\vbox`es to keep everything close together; making it more flexible is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \newdimen\hwid
    \newbox\hhbox\setbox\hhbox\hbox{h}
    \hwid=\wd\hhbox
    \vbox to10pt{%
        \vbox to0pt{\hbox{\hskip\hwid\vrule height0.5pt width5pt depth0pt}}%
        \vbox to10pt{\hbox{hello}}%
    }%
\end{document}
```

As far as I can tell, this also works with less exotic document class choices, like `article`:

[image: Results]

Is that at least vaguely what you're looking for?